# paragraph is not showing in a center in ionic 3

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am learning ionic and for that I was following [ionic framework document](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/). As mentioned in the link, to set attribute dynamically there is given example

`<div [attr.text-center]="isMD ? '' : null">I will be centered when isMD is true.</div>`.

But when I tried it to implement it didn't work! neither in browser nor in my android device.

```
<p [attr.text-center]="isMD ? '' : null"> paragraph in a center</p>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it happened?
where did I go wrong?

**Edit**

My .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `isMD` in your .ts file?

Comment: @99tharun No. I don't have that. Do I need that? and how to add it in .ts file?

Comment: Do you want to dynamically set the paragraph to center or by default you want it to appear center align?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p tag remaining same. you need to add **isMD** variable in .ts file

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {
  constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    if(this.plt.is('android')){
      isMD= true;
    }else{
      isMD= false;
    }

  }
}
```

Without this process you can done by another process using **ngClass**

in **.scss** paste following code

```
.center-text{
  text-align: center;
}
```

in **.ts** paste following code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {
  constructor() {
    isMD= true;
  }
}
```

in **.html** paste following code

```
<p [ngClass]="{'center-text': isMD}">paragraph in a center</p>
```

Comment: I understood your point, thanks.but in this case isMD is always true.

Comment: and in this case what is isMD? a simple user defined variable? or a variable for platform specific styles https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/

Comment: you mean that you need text center for android?

Comment: ok. thank you. can you help me with that? what should i write in function?

Comment: yes. exactly. text center for android. not for web or ios

Comment: but my question is, as i said in my question i was following ionic framework document and in there was isMD variable, so was that only  a simple user defined variable?

Comment: if you got any problem then u can add me in skype.. utpaul.sarkar after 8.00 pm

Answer (score 1):

If you by default want the text to appear center align simply add this attribute to your p tag

```
<p text-center>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac vehicula lorem.
</p>
```

If you want a dynamic behavior and depending on certain condition you want it to appear center align then you have to make a variable in the controller and change the value true/false and depending on that your text will appear center align so for that

```
<p [attr.text-center]="yourVariable ? '' : null">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac vehicula lorem.
</p>
```

Your .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-hello-ionic',
  templateUrl: 'hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {
  yourVariable:boolean;
  constructor() {
      yourVariable = true; // control your text alignment from here
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you out